# MS access how to make footer for only front page

Tags: ms-access

How do you make a footer ONLY for front page? I looked online, and everyone only asks for footer of last page but none for first page. Pls help

Comment: If you don't want a global footer, than don't do it.. Just make your "footer" in your front page. As simple as making a section in your front page.

Comment: its tricky because my front page's length isn't consistent as it changes depending on values. That being said, my "front page footer" will either move down to next page if front page is longer than usual, or move up if front page is emptier than usual.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting this code on your report footer's OnFormat procedure. Me.PageFooterSection.Visible = (Me.[Page] = 1)

And in order for it to work when printing, you may need to use the same code in the footer's OnPrint procedure.

Hope this helps.